# Libgdx Coordinate system in tablets

Tags: java, libgdx, coordinates

I was testing my "game" in my old phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace) and I gave it to my mom, so I'm using now a tablet (Samsung GT-P7300), but I'm facing a problem in the coordinates when I touch the screen. I configured in the AndroidManifest to be a portrait the orientation, so when I test the game, the screen "lies down" (expected behavior), but when I touch at the upper-left corner of the screen my game my log says the inverted position. Maybe you will understand with the image:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you tap the screen libgdx gives you the exact pixel of the event, using screen coordinates (y-down).

If you want your touch to be in camera units (y-up) you have to **unproject** it.

```
Vector3 touch = new Vector3();

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
        camera.unproject(touch.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        //touch.x and touch.y are your new touch point using camera coordinates.
...
```

Comment: Alright, now I recive negative values. It is normal? Won't it affect do position a sprite or something else?

Comment: negative numbers is because your camera shows part of the world in thje negative x and y axis